# Select one row matching condition or first, if there aren't any

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've got a table with some data. It looks like that:

```
MariaDB [lokatnik]> SELECT id_elixir, start_time FROM elixir ORDER BY start_time ASC;
+-----------+------------+
| id_elixir | start_time |
+-----------+------------+
|         3 | 00:00:00   |
|         1 | 12:30:00   |
|         2 | 13:30:00   |
+-----------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I need to select exactly one row matching time condition - say - start_time > some_time.

For example:

- when some_time is 10:00, then I need a row with id_elixir = 1 (first row with time more than 10:00),
- when some_time is 13:00, then I need a row with id_elixir = 2 (like above),
- when some_time is 14:00, then I need row with id_elixir = 3.

How can I get this row using SQL (and MySQL/MariaDB DBMS)?

Comment: What is the `start_time` column data type?

Comment: comparing time with 00:00:00 is pretty impossible since it may be same day midnight or next day midnight. So `> '14:00'` will fail and will return unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, something like this will work for you:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  elixir
WHERE
  CASE
    WHEN start_time BETWEEN CAST('10:00:00' AS TIME) AND CAST('13:00:00' AS
      TIME)
    THEN id =1
    WHEN start_time BETWEEN CAST('13:00:00' AS TIME) AND CAST('14:00:00' AS
      TIME)
    THEN id         =2
    WHEN start_time > CAST('14:00:00' AS TIME)
    THEN id         =3
    ELSE true
```

But you can actually check that by using simple boolean operators:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  elixir
WHERE
  (
    start_time BETWEEN CAST('10:00:00' AS TIME) AND CAST('13:00:00' AS TIME)
  AND id =1
  )
OR
  (
    start_time BETWEEN CAST('13:00:00' AS TIME) AND CAST('14:00:00' AS TIME)
  AND id =2
  )
OR
  (
    start_time > CAST('14:00:00' AS TIME)
  AND id       =3
```